# How to solve $ \dfrac{ dy}{dx} = xy\cdot ((xy)^2-1)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this differential equation:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=xy\cdot ((xy)^2-1)$$

We must find a common solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be rewritten as a [Bernoulli ODE](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx) defined as:

> $$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n \tag{1}$$

Manipulating your ODE a little bit gives that form:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+xy=x^3 y^3$$
Therefore, we should divide both sides by $y^3$ to obtain:
$$\frac{1}{y^3}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{x}{y^2}=x^3$$
Note that all Bernoulli Differential Equations can be reduced to a linear ODE by using the substitution $z=y^{1-n}$ on $(1)$. Therefore, one should apply the substitution:
$$z=\frac{1}{y^2}\implies \frac{dz}{dx}=-\frac{2}{y^3}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$$
This gives a [linear ODE](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx):
$$\frac{dz}{dx}-2xz=-2x^3 \tag{2}$$
One can solve this using the following [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor):
$$\mu(x)=e^{\int -2x~dx}=e^{-x^2}$$
Can you continue? After solving for $z(x)$, be sure to substitute back to obtain $y(x)$.